# Which assembly will each namespace go into?

Tags: c#

Out of curiosity, in my c# project/solution which assembly will each namespace go into? How does it decide which namespace to put into which assembly?

**Edit:**
Was just a bit confused, I thought that there was some kind of correlation between which namespace go in which assembly.

Comment: Are you looking for the [Framework Design Guidelines from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/), or for opinions? It would also look like you're asking this question the wrong way around, why are you out to create multiple assemblies? Classes, namespaces and assemblies all are organization units, you organise stuff in a way that you and your team deem fit, keeping in mind general recommendations such as in the linked guidelines. One assembly can contain mulitple namespaces, and one namespace can span multiple assemblies.

Comment: Namespaces don't go into assemblies; types do. A namespace can be split across any number of assemblies, and an assembly can contain any number of namespace-qualified types. Normally each project builds only one assembly, and the name of that assembly is configurable with the project.

Comment: Eeeeh, what? A namespace doesn´t go anywhere. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: To be practical, start with whatever you feel good, and then use tools like NDepend to check whether you make mistakes, https://www.ndepend.com/Res/PDF/Defining_.NET_Components_as_Namespaces_NDepend.pdf Then soon you figure out what should be changed.

Comment: I would recommend you to rephrase the question in order to avoid a broad set of answers around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each project usually builds one assembly, regardless of namespaces. So there isn't a direct relationship between namespaces and assemblies, since you can declare multiple namespaces in a single project, and can declare the same namespace across different assemblies.

However, [the usual recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-assemblies-and-dlls) (h.t.  CodeCaster) is to name the projects, their output assemblies, and their namespaces consistently, so that it's clear which namespace comes from which assembly. So if you make a project named `MyCompany.MyApp.csproj`, it by default creates an assembly named `MyCompany.MyApp.dll` (or `.exe`), and new files you create will be in the `MyCompany.MyApp` namespace. You can have child namespaces within your project, typically corresponding to the folder structure in the project, e.g. folder `Section` contains types in the namespace `MyCompany.MyApp.Section`. But again, this is all convention - you can change the `namespace` directives in each file to do something different.

Answer (score 0):

> which assembly will each namespace go into?

There is ZERO correlation between namespace and assembly.

The compiled class goes into the assembly created by the project - every project one assembly. Namespaces can be used on many assemblies and there is simply ZERO correlation technically, though CONVENTION says you keep correlated namespaces in one assembly - the compiler does not care.

At the end, TYPES go into an assembly, and TYPES have a namespace - but nothing in the build process cares as decision where it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it very simple. Assembly is phsical grouping but NameSpace is logical grouping. Assembly can have more namespaces.

`System.Data` is a namespace, `System.Data.DLL` is an assembly